# How to get equal size slice of array literately in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, slice

For example with array `let array = [1, 3, -5, 2, 6]`, I want get this output: with equal size(N) of slice of array.

if N = 2, then output: 
`[1,3] [3,-5] [-5,2] [2,6]`

if N = 3, then output:
`[1,3,-5] [3,-5,2] [-5,2,6]`

/ / / Update my code as below, `winSize` is using to define the size of slice array, which is come from readLine()

```
class windowSize {
    var resultArray = [Int]()

    func execTest() {
        print("please give the window size W and length(S) of array, seperated by space")
        if let firstLine = readLine() {
            let firstLineArray = firstLine.compactMap{Int(String($0))}
            let winSize = firstLineArray[0]

            print("please give the test array with S length")
            if let arr1 = readLine() {
                let arr = arr1.compactMap{Int(String($0))}
                // print(arr)

                // get each slice array with window size length
                let slicedArray = arr.neighbors

                // get max value in each slice array
                for ele in slicedArray {
                    let max = ele.max()
                    resultArray.append(max!)
                }

                print("resultarray", resultArray)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Collection {
    var neighbors: [SubSequence] {
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
        return indices.dropLast().map {
            return self[$0..<(index($0, offsetBy: 2, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex)]
        }
    }
}

windowSize().execTest()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate your collection indices dropping the last one and return each element along with its subsequent neighbor:

```
extension Collection {
    var neighbors: [SubSequence] {
        indices.dropLast().map {
            self[$0..<(index($0, offsetBy: 2, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex)]
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let array = [1, 3, -5, 2, 6]
let chunks = array.neighbors  // [[1, 3], [3, -5], [-5, 2], [2, 6]]
let maxValues = chunks.compactMap{$0.max()}  // [3, 3, 2, 6]
```

---

If you need more than two elements:

```
extension Collection {
    func customChunk(of n: Int) -> [SubSequence] {
        indices.dropLast(n-1).map {
            self[$0..<(index($0, offsetBy: n, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex)]
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let chunks3 = array.customChunk(of: 3)  // [[1, 3, -5], [3, -5, 2], [-5, 2, 6]]
let maxValues3 = chunks.compactMap{$0.max()}  // [3, 3, 6]
```

Comment: great, then how could convert this slice array to array type? I found ```Array(array.neighbors)``` not worked

Comment: What you need is to initialize one array for each element/subsequence `array.neighbors.map(Array.init)`? Why don't you use the subsequence / ArraySlice ?

Comment: Another option is to change the return type and initialise each element on the fly `extension Collection {
    var neighbors: [[Element]] {
        indices.dropLast().map {
            .init(self[$0..<(index($0, offsetBy: 2, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex)])
        }
    }
}`

Comment: man, I need use a var for offsetBy ```offsetBy: some global var```, could I do that?

Comment: I want to use ```ArraySlice```, but don't know how to iterate with each one, that is the problem. Well, I update my question, the slice size is a variable and the slice move one position in the array for each time.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question and show your attempt

Comment: Update my code, ```winSize``` is the size of slice array, which is from userInput. So it is a variable.

Comment: @ChuckZHB Swift 5 or later you can use `Character` property `wholeNumberValue` ==> `compactMap{$0.wholeNumberValue}` instead of `compactMap{Int(String($0))}`

Comment: Really busy today:( I see your post, but I'm not fully understood it. Your answer is good, only that I'm not so deep in Swift grammar, need some time... And mean time, ```ArraySlice``` could do the thing perfect as ielyamani's answer. Anyway, as you answer firstly, I would accept your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
func windows<T>(in a: [T], ofSize w: Int) -> [[T]] {
    //You could decide here what you want to return if w is invalid
    if w > a.count || w <= 0 {
        return []
    }

    var output = [[T]]()
    for i in 0..<a.count-w+1 {
        output.append(Array(a[i..<i+w]))
    }
    return output
}
```

And here are some use cases:

```
windows(in: [1, 3, -5, 2, 6], ofSize: 2) //[[1, 3], [3, -5], [-5, 2], [2, 6]]
windows(in: [1, 3, -5, 2, 6], ofSize: 3) //[[1, 3, -5], [3, -5, 2], [-5, 2, 6]]
```

---

### Sliding window maximum

Calculating the Sliding Window Maximum by first generating all the subarrays is wasteful:

```
let ws = windows(in: [1, 3, -5, 2, 6], ofSize: 3)
let maxs = ws.compactMap { $0.max() } //[3, 3, 6]
```

Below you can find a couple of better solutions:

### Approach 1:

Here are two approaches to calculate the classic Sliding Window Maximum:

```
func slidingWindowMax(_ a: [Int], _ w: Int) -> [Int] {
    let n = a.count

    if n < 2 || w == 1  {
        return a
    }

    var maxLeft = Array(repeating: 0, count: n)
    var maxRight = Array(repeating: 0, count: n)

    maxLeft[0] = a[0]
    maxRight[n - 1] = a[n - 1]

    for i in 1..<n {
        maxLeft[i] = i % w == 0 ? a[i] : max(maxLeft[i - 1], a[i])

        let j = n - i - 1
        maxRight[j] = j % w == 0 ? a[j] : max(maxRight[j + 1], a[j])
    }

    var slidingWindowMax = Array(repeating: 0, count: n - w + 1)

    var k = 0

    for i in 0 ..< n - w + 1 {
        slidingWindowMax[k] = max(maxRight[i], maxLeft[i + w - 1])
        k += 1
    }

    return slidingWindowMax
}
```

### Approach 2:

```
func slidingWindowMax2(_ array: [Int], _ window: Int) -> [Int]{

    let n = array.count

    if n < 2 || window == 1 {
        return array
    }

    var result = Array(repeating: 0, count: n - window + 1)
    var maxIndex = -1, maximum = Int.max

    for start in 0 ..< n - window + 1 {
        let end = start + window - 1
        if maxIndex < start {
            maxIndex = start
            maximum = array[start]
            for next in start + 1 ... end {
                if array[next] > maximum {
                    maxIndex = next
                    maximum = array[next]
                }
            }
        } else {
            if array[end] > maximum {
                maxIndex = end;
                maximum = array[end]
            }
        }
        result[start] = maximum
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late, it is quite messy today for me... I check it and works well.

Comment: @ChuckZHB What you are looking for is the sliding window maximum, that's a different question from what you initially asked.

Comment: well, I have connect your code with mine. Just ignore above comment, I will remove it now.

Comment: it is quite long time, but should it be ```maxRight[j] = (j + 1) % w == 0...```  in Approach 1?