# Swift: convert an array into x arrays with n elements each?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, slice

I have an array in Swift:

```swift
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I need to have X number of arrays each has n elements, say n = 3:

```swift
[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]
```

So that if elements in the end are less than n the last sub-array will have whatever remaining.

I thought about using `stride`:

```swift
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let n = 3
var subarrays = [[Int]]()
for i in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: n) {
    let slice = array[i..<min(i+n, array.count)]
    subarrays.append(Array(slice))
}
```

I wonder if there's a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the issue with your code?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789716/9223839) is one alternative

Comment: Take a look at [Chunked](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Chunked.md) in the Swift Algorithm Package

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395766/swift-what-is-the-right-way-to-split-up-a-string-resulting-in-a-string-wi